# Silverlight: Enterprise-grade push notifications

Tags: wcf, silverlight, notifications, scalability

We are building a Silverlight-based system in the financial domain. We need to push notifications/stream data from the server to the Silverlight client. We use Silverlight 4 for the client and Windows Server 2003/IIS6 on the server side (this excludes AppFabric).

So far I haven't been able to find a Silverlight-compatible data push solution that would be secure and scalable. Out of the box sockets don't seem to support SSL and the PollingDuplexHttpBinding doesn't seem to scale for the web farm implementations/failover. It also looks like that IIS is not the best platform for long polling applications.

Has anybody successfully implemented an enterprise-grade notification push solution for Silverlight and what technologies/products have you used?

Comment: In what way doesn't PollingDuplexHttpBinding scale for the web farm implementations/failover?

Comment: Take a look at SignalR: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Comment: @ChuiTey - the implementation of the polling binding queues the messages in the memory of a specific server creating server affinity and lack of resistance to server failure. See here: http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2009/09/scale-out-of-silverlight-http-polling.html

Comment: Have you thought of using a Comet server?

Comment: @Leo - SignalR doesn't seem to be scalable according to this: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Scaling-out-SignalR. Any more recent information or personal experience using it in a web farm?

Comment: @Rus - I think any potential solution will involve a Comet-type server. Any particular one that's compatible with Silverlight/WCF and is scalable that you can recommend?

Comment: Comet servers are pretty scaleable a lot of financial systems use them. An example of this  http://www.marketsplus.com.au/evolve who use a Comet server to pump price info up to their Silverlight client. Some Comet implementations are http://meteorserver.org/, http://pokein.com/ or http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/ .

Comment: @Rus - Thanks! MarketsPlus looks great. Do you know which one of the Comet servers they are using?

Comment: The reason I know they're using a Comet server is they did a technical article on their approach.

Comment: It looks like they are using WebSync based on this: http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/learn/clients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comet servers are pretty scaleable a lot of financial systems use them.

An example of this [marketsplus.com.au/evolve](http://www.marketsplus.com.au/evolve) who use a Comet server to pump price info up to their Silverlight client.

Some Comet implementations are [meteorserver.org](http://www.meteorserver.org), [pokein.com](http://www.pokein.com) or [frozenmountain.com/websync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync).