# WCF RIA send Server notification

Tags: wcf-ria-services

Is it possible to notify all clients from the server using WCF RIA ?
We have a requirement in which when we save a data from our Silverlight 5 client,all clients should be notified. we use WCF RIA on the backend,

Would appreicate if someone can point me to the right direction !

Thanks !

Comment: I do not think you can do this with WCF RIA Services, but it can be easily done with SignalR: http://signalr.net/

Comment: Thanks ! I looked into SignalR and could not find a sample using WCF RIA as the backend, I was able to make it work with Asp.Net MVC as the backend. Do you have a sample code with WCf RIA ? We are using Silverlight as the front end.

Answer (score 1):

I Agree with Leo about SignalR and it shouldn't be hard to do, however has to be said that Silverlight supports FullDuplex, so you can make your client to call your server in order to estabilish the connection and get the callback. Here's a sample http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645027(v=vs.95).aspx. Keep in mind that in order to use fullduplex you silverlight client have to open ports (4502-4534).
Ther's finally the idea to use a Comet pattern, for which I drive you to this question: [Silverlight: Enterprise-grade push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079516/silverlight-enterprise-grade-push-notifications) however I've encountered some problems with FF/Chrome and long polling

HTH

Comment: This sample uses WCF services and not WCf RIA Services.

Comment: yep you're right. And can't you rely on it ? WCF Ria Services is built upon WCF, if the question it's about EXCLUSIVELY WCF Ria, then the answer, is simply No, You can't, don't even try

Comment: @mCasamento Is it okay to add a new WCF service , just for this duplex purpose to our existing WCF RIA silverlight application ?

Comment: @user636525 if can afford to use tcp port range 4502-4534 for communication between server and client, then yes, no problem.